# Android Studio (Kotlin) and AWS SDK setup

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, aws-sdk

He

I have no more ideas how to setup AWS SDK (credentials) and so on to use it for Android development.

Will be great to get step-by-step manual.

This manual doesn't help
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html

I cannot understand where to place this files with credentials in Android and how it looks if I need to use same SDK in application on mobile.

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.11' // Core AWS SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.11' // Example: AWS S3 SDK
    // Add other AWS service SDK dependencies as needed
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // ... Other existing dependencies ...
}
```